# name splitting regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to split a string (a persons name) into components: prefix (Dr, Mr, Miss, etc), given, middle, family, and suffix (Jr, III, etc...).

Prefixes and suffixes can be a known list of options.

Edge cases for double barreled family names like 'da Vinci' or 'di Caprio' don't really bother me too much. The da's and di's will just be dropped in the middle name, or if a middle is given (i.e. 4 names are found that don't match a prefix or suffix) then everything after the second name is dropped in the family name.

I'm thinking about writing the regex myself... but before I go and reinvent the wheel, I wonder if anyone has something that works I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't mind about 'da Vinci' etc, why don't you just split on space?

Comment: okay, if you know Mr Leo di Caprio you can use something like this:
`/(\w+\s+)+/` so, now, after this regex, you can sort string array and move each string for each category.

Comment: Thanks. /(\w+\s+)+/ would work. Though I'm sure not everyone is going to enter a prefix and suffix. Nor would they always enter a middle name or last name. Yes, I could just split the words and sort it out later, but that's what regex is for. If theres a cool way of doing it in one regex test that would be awesome. It would have to recognize and sort correctly: Leonardo Wilhelm DiCaprio, Mr. Leo DiCaprio, Leo DiCaprio, Lio, Mr. DiCaprio, Leo Jr., Leonardo DiCaprio III, etc...

Comment: which language do you intend to use for your regex ? (java , c# ...) Have you got a few examples and the output expected ?

Comment: I also have the same issue, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal in perl (I did not find a language or regex flavor requirement).
Perl supports non-capturing groups, e.g. "(?:\w+)", which I consider needed to stay below 10 captured groups.
I am using "\w+" almost everywhere, for simplicity. Names can therefor contain "_" and digits. If you do not like that, use "[[:alpha:]]+" instead.

```
perl -pe"s/(?:(Dr\.|Mr\.) )?(?:(\w+)(?: (\w+(?: \w+)*))? )?(?:(\w+) (Jr\.|I+))|(?:(Dr\.|Mr\.) )?(?:(\w+)(?: (\w+(?: \w+)*))? )?(\w+)/pre\1\6 give\2\7 middle\3\8 fam\4\9 post\5/"
```

For demonstration purposes, the code replaces, while inserting field names.
Please extract the requested regex and fill in the missing pres and posts.

What I consider the trick is to have one big alternative "|", which prefers matches with a postfix.
The fields are filled by using two groups each, one from the first, one from the second alternative. Only one of each pair is non-empty.
I  tested with a test text file, containing combination of

- prefix present
- postfix present
- given present
- middle present (assuming that more middles work too)
- second middle present

All test cases have a family name.
"Superman II" and "Madonna" would both only have a family name, hope that is OK, the super hero movie gets a suffix.
"Dr. Who" has a prefix and a family name.

I.e. I ignored the "Di"s, as you permitted.
I consider the output plausible.